# SuperSet add calculated field to existing dataset

Tags: apache-superset

Superset users want to add calculated fields to their datasets, but they run into an error:

> Changing this dataset is forbidden

Users have the following roles:

- Gamma
- tables_modify: [can tables on Superset, can save on Datasource, can get on Datasource, can datasources on Superset, menu access on Tables, can fetch datasource metadata on Superset, can read on Dataset, can write on Dataset]
- DB: [database access on [their TimeScale DB], datasource access on [the dataset they want to edit]]
- sql_lab

I can't find the role missing for them to be able to edit their datasets. They have read and write permission on it, and are the ones creating the datasets in the first place.

I looked into the database properties but could not find any setting there either. Moreover with admin role I am able to edit datasets so I guess what's missing here is a user role, I just can't find which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [official documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/security) says, Gamma users are not able to alter data sources. Alpha users can add and alter data sources.
Additional information can be read further in that document:

> If the user does not have the `all_datasource_access` permission
> granted, the user will **only be able to see** Slices or explore the
> data sources that are granted to them.